# Optimise Neo4j Query

Tags: optimization, neo4j, cypher

```
match (m:Server)-[r]-(n:Middleware)-[r1]-(o:OperatingSystem),
(y:DeploymentUnit{name:n.name+m.name}) merge(y)-[:STRATEGIC_RUNS_ON]->(o) merge(y)<-[:STRATEGIC_OUT_RUNS_ON]-(o)
```

I was running this query but it took more than one hour to complete.Is there a way I can optimise this query.
Server nodes:10035,
Middleware nodes:2334,
OperatingSystem nodes:43,
DeploymentUnit nodes:5014.

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1. Do you really need to add `DeploymentUnit` nodes? Redundant data should only be added when really necessary (e.g., for critical performance optimization). 2. You do not need a pair of relationships going in opposite directions if they would always be paired up. Just use one relationship type, as going in opposite direction is just as easy and efficient.

Comment: @cybersam we need DeploymentUnit nodes its a part of our use case.

Comment: But `DeploymentUnit` nodes are not logically necessary. You can get the same information with a slightly more complex query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can improve this query in the following ways:

**Create an Index on the name property of DeploymentUnit Label which is used for matching**

```
CREATE INDEX FOR (n:DeploymentUnit) ON (n.name)
```

**Avoiding the cartesian product in the query using WITH**

```
MATCH (m:Server)-[r]-(n:Middleware)-[r1]-(o:OperatingSystem)
WITH n.name+m.name as du_name, o
MATCH (y:DeploymentUnit{name: du_name}) 
MERGE (y)-[:STRATEGIC_RUNS_ON]->(o) 
MERGE (y)<-[:STRATEGIC_OUT_RUNS_ON]-(o)
```